# Jquery.Validate stops validating any controls once I add @Html.DropDownListFor to the form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form with multiple controls that ARE validated using Jquery.Validate.  They all work until I add a new row with a  @Html.DropDownListFor.  No errors appear in the console, the validator simply stops working.  When I say stops working, I mean nothing is highlighted in red and my btnClick says the form is Valid.

```
//This works
<div class="col-sm-5">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PublicationName, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PublicationName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

//Adding this causes everything to stop validating
//Using the Select2 Plugin
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.JournalistId, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JournalistId,
(SelectList)ViewBag.Journalists,  new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

The Resulting HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
<label class="control-label" for="JournalistId">Author</label>
<select class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Author must be a number." id="JournalistId" name="JournalistId" data-select2-id="JournalistId" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-describedby="JournalistId-error"><option value="" data-select2-id="2">Select</option>
<option value="346">Name 1</option>
<option value="381">Name 2</option>
</select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1" style="width: 357.5px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-JournalistId-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-JournalistId-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Select">Select</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
 </div>
```

My Model

```
    [Display(Name = "Publication Name")]
    public string PublicationName { get; set; }

    public int? PublicationId { get; set; }

    public string Journalist { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Author")]
    public int? JournalistId { get; set; }
```

My Script

```
$(function () {

    $('.btnNext').click(function (e) {
        if ($("#form1").valid()) {
            alert('valid');
        } else {
            alert('not valid');
        }
    });

    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            PublicationName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            }
        },
        messages: {
            PublicationName: {
                required: "Please enter a Publication Name",
                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
            }
        },
        errorElement: "em",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
            error.addClass("help-block");

            // Add `has-feedback` class to the parent div.form-group
            // in order to add icons to inputs
            element.parents(".col-sm-5").addClass("has-feedback");

            if (element.prop("type") === "checkbox") {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent("label"));
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }

            // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
            if (!element.next("span")[0]) {
                $("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>").insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        success: function (label, element) {
            // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
            if (!$(element).next("span")[0]) {
                $("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>").insertAfter($(element));
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents(".col-sm-5").addClass("has-error").removeClass("has-success");
            $(element).next("span").addClass("glyphicon-remove").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents(".col-sm-5").addClass("has-success").removeClass("has-error");
            $(element).next("span").addClass("glyphicon-ok").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You cannot dynamically add new fields to a form without calling `.rules()` to dynamically add rules to the new fields.  An exception would be any fields which contain inline attributes that are used for rule declaration.

Comment: I'm not adding the controls dynamically. I meant, when designing the form, everything works right up until I add the dropdown for then the entire form stops Validating.

Comment: Then you need to show us the rendered HTML markup.

Comment: I've added the Resulting HTML

Comment: Argh, it turns out i havejquery.validate.unobtrusive.js loaded and once I removed it, the controls all started validating properly.

Comment: That’s because Unobtrusive Validation constructs and calls `.validate()`, which completely takes precedence over your call to this method.  Tagging the question originally with "Unobtrusive Validation" may have helped us to help you.

Comment: I also don't understand how it could have been broken simply by adding a dropdown.  You failed to explain how Unobtrusive suddenly came into play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, it turns out i havejquery.validate.unobtrusive.js loaded and once I removed it, the controls all started validating properly.

Comment: Right, because you can only call `.validate()` one time and all other calls are ignored.  Since Unobtrusive Validation automatically constructs/calls `.validate()`, yours is ignored.  However, your original question was impossible to answer because it does not explain how it could have been working before you added the dropdown.  Either you had Unobtrusive installed or you didn't.